# Install Teamviewer on Ubuntu 17.04 with 64-bits architecture

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, dependencies, 17.04, teamviewer

Trying to install the `.deb` package from Teamviewer's website gives unmet dependencies on 64-bit architecture, because the downloaded file is for 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution at the corresponding other question. BTW I resolved dependencies by installing via Ubuntu Software which is default on double click the DEB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step by step guide how to install Teamviewer on 64-bit architecture running Ubuntu 17.04

**Step 1**

Download the deb package from [Teamviewer Website](https://www.teamviewer.com/fr/download/linux/)

**Step 2**

In a terminal, type:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libasound2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

**Step 3**

Now you can either run the downloaded .deb file **by double-clicking** it or run it in the terminal by typing:

```
dpkg -i /path_to_your_download_folder/downloaded_file.deb
```

**Note:**
I did not test on previous releases of Ubuntu, some dependencies may vary but the overall process remains the same.
If you have any comments or remark, please feel free to improve!